# Angular js directive model change not reflected in function

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive defined like so:

```
.directive("datepicker", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            date: '=',
            filterfnc: '&'
        },
        replace: true,
        controller: ["$scope", '$http', '$resource', 'services', function ($scope, $http, $resource, services) {
        $scope.RunFilter = function () {
            $scope.date = '9-16-2013';
            $scope.filterfnc();
        }
    }]
```

I am accessing the directive like so:

```
<datepicker date="MyDate" filterfnc="LoadValue()"></datepicker>
```

MyDate is a Model value that will be used in the function LoadValue().  The problem I'm having is even though the value is set in the directive, it's not showing in the LoadValue function.

```
$scope.MyDate= '';

    $scope.LoadValue= function () {
        var params = { Date: $scope.MyDate };
        ...
    }
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Everything seems correct and I'm getting no errors.

Comment: I dont see a call to `RunFilter()`;

Comment: RunFilter() gets called by some other action.  That's not my issue.  When I debug it, the date gets set and then the filterfnc does get fired.  When I step into that { which takes me to LoadValue }, I see that $scope.MyDate is still set to ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really strange and I would love to see other answers. It seems that it takes the two-way binding a while to update or something. I got it to work like this:

```
app.directive("datepicker", function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            date: '=',
            filterfnc: '&'
        },
        replace: true,
        controller: function ($scope) {            
            $scope.RunFilter = function () {                    
                $scope.date = '9-16-2013';
                $timeout(function(){
                    $scope.filterfnc();
                });                 
            }
            $scope.RunFilter();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure, but I guess you should either use `LoadValue`, without `()`, as the `filterfnc` attribute value, or have `LoadValue` defined as

```
$scope.LoadValue = function() {
    return function() {
        var params = { date: $scope.MyDate};
        //The rest of your function
    };
}
```